# Pandas OFFSET and MATCH function with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula

I have this excel formula that needs to be applied on a pandas dataframe

`=IF(OFFSET(list!$B$1,MATCH($X1,list!$A:$A,0)-1,0)=0,"",OFFSET(list!$B$1,MATCH($X1,list!$A:$A,0)-1,0))`

dataframe: **list**

```
A       B           C    
24309   Pepsi       US
45768   McDonalds   US
45638   Apple       Ireland
59374   Google      Ireland
```

dataframe 2: **new_list**

```
X         Y
24309     ?
45768     ?
45638
59374
```

The goal is to populate the `Y` column of the second `new_list` dataframe if the value in `X` matches a value in range `A1:A4`

I'm struggling with the best approach to do this. Can someone point me to the right direction? I was thinking of using panda `groupby` with `np.where` to compare and take the value of `B` column when there is  a match.

**Edit**

```
new_list['Y'] = np.where(list['A'] == new_list['X'], list['B'], np.nan)
```

The solution above gives the same results but is this the right way to define such an **Excel** formula in **Pandas?**

Comment: @nixon - no the whole column range needs to be used. i used `A1:A4` for the seek of the sample data above.

Comment: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: np.where is the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_list['Y'] = np.where(list['A'] == new_list['X'], list['B'], np.nan)
```

The code above was implemented and provides the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and most efficient way is to apply a mask over the values. Here you could find a sample dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"Date" : ['2013-11-22', '2013-10-24', '2013-09-24', '2013-02-15'],
"Fruit" : ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery'], 
"Num" : [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2],
"Color" : ['Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green']
})
```

where after you could apply this mask, print out the mask to see result, or you could use the mask in a way that you like.

```
mask = (df1["Fruit"] == df1["Color"])
print(mask)
```

I hope that helps.